# как использоваиь Brodcast с несколькьми активити

Tags: java, android

У меня есть запущенный сервис в котором происходит проверка соединения к серверу. При обрыве соедиения сервис отправляет brodcast в main активити и там уже происходит оповещение пользователя.
Отправка brodcast происходит сл. образом

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.BROADCAST);
intent.putExtra(Main.PARAM, Main.FAIL);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Проблема в том, что во время обрыва соединения пользователь может находится на другой активити и в случае передачи бродкаста, приложение с ошибкой вылетит на главное активити. Как грамотно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Значит вам надо создать обработчик разрыва соединения.

Comment: можно ссылку на пример или наводящую статью

Comment: Погугли ссылок много.

Comment: по запросу обработчик, всплывает обработчик нажатий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что можно создать слушатель в базовой activity. И надо использовать intentFilter. Пример можно посмотреть тут [пример](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-register-broadcastreceiver-in-android-activity/)